# hashing/encoding a parameter send in url through javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am sending an id in the URL of page like autom.ca/quote.php?id=12345
it is being send through java script and received by php I want to hash this uri so that it can be send as autom.ca/quote.php?id=hashedvalue and when I decode it, it should return me the exact value being send before hashing. I am using java script for sending the id and PHP to retrieve it any solutions?

Comment: HASHing is a one way process. So thats not possible

Comment: any other recomendation?

Comment: Yea dont bother, anything you do in javascript can either be turned off by the browser, or messed with by the end user so there is little point in bothering

Comment: Is there some reason to even do it? It's standard way how backend and frontend work that data which is transfer is not hashed.  You as a user can basicly get anything from client side running jS so if someone really want he will know what you send anyway :)

Comment: actually a quotation is sent to a supplier and after adding a markup i can send that quotation to the client issue is in the current scenario both the supplier and client pages are using id as parameter now the supplier can view which quotation the company ha sent to the client because they both have the same id

Comment: The normal reason for soing this is that you want to hide that fact this is the first order or something like that. In that case just start your id on your database at 20,000 or something like that

Comment: But hopefully you are pointing them at different scripts

Comment: yea they are pointed at different scripts

Comment: This only makes sense if you generate the hash on the server already.

Comment: exactly i was just thinking about that @CBroe

Answer (score -1):

There is an excellent library for this - https://hashids.org/php/

It generates short, unique, non-sequential IDs from numbers. It converts numbers like `347` into strings like `yr8`, or array of numbers like `[27, 986]` into `3kTMd`. And of course it allows you to convert them back.